# How to remove images from posts description from RSS feed?

Tags: php, html, xml, rss, simplexml

I'm using the following code to get the RSS feed:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($website);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
}
```

But some of them contain images in two format:

1- Tags:

```
<img src='' alt='' style='' />
```

2- Encoded tags:

```
 &lt;img style="" align="" alt="" src=""/&gt;
```

How to get the description without any images?

Comment: get the description values and use strip tags or use html decodefirst then use strip tags

Comment: @Ghost, What is html decode?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear at the moment, because although you've shown some code, it's not a [mcve] - you haven't shown a sample input, the output you get at the moment, and the output you want instead. I think you need to *break your problem down* (a key step in all debugging): if `$item->description` contains everything you want, but also some extra parts, you can just take that string as your input, and forget about the XML. So your task becomes "write some function `stripImages($description)` which takes a string, and returns that string with unwanted parts removed".